# Wordpress load more posts on front page (page.php) - loads empty content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've made load more button on the bottom on my page.php. Unfortunately, it doesn't load anything despite of showing success in ajax.

Code as follows:

myloadmore.js

```
jQuery(function($){


$('.load-articles').on('click', function() {
    var self = $(this),
            page = self.data('page'),
            newPage = page + 1,

            ajaxurl = self.data('url'),
            post_types = self.data('types'),
            post_template = self.data('tmpl');

    $.ajax({
        url  : ajaxurl,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            page   : page,
            types  : post_types,
            action : 'more_articles_ajax',
            tmpl   : post_template
        },
        beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
            $('.load-articles').text('Ładuję...'); // change the button text, you can also add a preloader image
        },
        error : function( response ) {
            console.log( response );
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response) {
                self.data('page', newPage);
                $('.loadmore-container').hide().append(response).fadeIn(500);
                $('.load-articles').text('zobacz więcej');
            } else {
                $('.load-articles').remove();
            }
        }
    });
  });
});
```

my function in functions.php

```
function more_articles_ajax() {

    $paged = $_POST['page'] + 1;
    $types = $_POST['types'];
    $tmpl = $_POST['tmpl'];

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'   => array($types),
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'order' => 'ASC',
    ) );
    if( $query->have_posts() ):
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', $tmpl);
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_articles_ajax', 'more_articles_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_more_articles_ajax', 'more_articles_ajax');
```

and page content:

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
  'numberposts' => 999,
  'post_type'   => array('news'),
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'posts_per_page' => 2,
  'paged' => get_query_var('page'),
  'page' => $paged
);
$latest_services = new WP_Query ( $args );

$i = 0;
?>
 <?php if ($latest_services->have_posts()): while ($latest_services->have_posts()) : $latest_services->the_post();?>

//some posts

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="loadmore-container"></div>
<div class="loadmore column load-articles" data-page="1" data-types="news" data-tmpl="article-item" data-url="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>">see more</div>

<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Edit:
Ok, I just have to add, that when entering sth as www.home-url/page/2/ I can see that my content is paged. However, when I add my pagination template, it doesn't show anything (but it works good on other pages).